# how to queue or buffer a series of commands in thread safe manner?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, queue, buffer

I am sending several command messages through UDP port. how can i queue them in a background safe thread while the program continues its service..

the commands i want to send are like this:

```
 GlobalUDP.UDPClient.Send(IPCmd, IPCmd.Length, new System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.255"), 30303));

 GlobalUDP.UDPClient.Send(IPCmd2, IPCmd.Length, new System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.255"), 30303));

GlobalUDP.UDPClient.Send(IPCmd3, IPCmd.Length, new System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.255"), 30303));
```

any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use a [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx)

The program's main thread can use [`BlockingCollection.Add()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287137.aspx) to add items to the queue.

Then your background thread would use [`GetConsumingEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx) to output the data, like so (where `queue` is the BlockingCollection):

```
foreach (var item in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    // Process item using GlobalUDP.UDPClient.Send()
}
```

When your main thread has finished enqueuing items and you want the background thread to exit, you call [`BlockingCollection.CompleteAdding()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287086.aspx) and it will terminate the `foreach` being done by the background thread.

You would write a wrapper class for the data needed by `GlobalUDP.UDPClient.Send()` and use that as the element type of the BlockingCollection.